# Rblpapi: Is there a way to run these requests as a batch?

Tags: r, rblpapi

My code

```
library(Rblpapi)
library(purrr)
blpConnect()
tickers = c("AAPL US Equity", "VOD LN Equity")
adjustmentFactors = setNames({
  tickers %>% map(function(ticker){
    res = bds(
      security = ticker
      , field = "EQY_DVD_ADJUST_FACT"
      , overrides = c("CORPORATE_ACTIONS_FILTER"="ABNORMAL_CASH|CAPITAL_CHANGE|NORMAL_CASH")
    )
    message(ticker)
    res
  })
}, tickers)
```

This takes a long time to run because each call to `bds` is a separate request. Is there a way to package this up into a single request? Or maybe some other way of speeding it up?

Comment: Yes, you can request all of them at once and then combine the list. Could you please provide some of the tickers you are requesting and the libraries you are loading? I'll come up with an example.

Comment: @tester - I have updated with better example code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I mesread your question a bit and thought it was a `bdp` or `bdh` call. As can be seen from the doucmentation of Rblpapi, `bds` only takes single tickers as an argument. Anyway, here's my approach:

```
tickers = c("AAPL US Equity", "VOD LN Equity", "BMW GY Equity")
get_bds <- function(x){
  bds(
    security = x
    , field = "EQY_DVD_ADJUST_FACT"
    , overrides = c("CORPORATE_ACTIONS_FILTER"="ABNORMAL_CASH|CAPITAL_CHANGE|NORMAL_CASH")
  )
}

test <- lapply(tickers, FUN = get_bds)
> head(test[[1]], 3)
  Adjustment Date Adjustment Factor Adjustment Factor Flag Adjustment Factor Operator Type
1      2020-11-06            1.0000                      1                               2
2      2020-08-31            4.0000                      3                               1
3      2020-08-07            0.9982                      1                               2
```